# Mahout : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout

I am trying to get mahout working and I am getting the following error :

```
3/05/16 22:48:53 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/05/16 22:48:53 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1119"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:430)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.ItemIDIndexMapper.map(ItemIDIndexMapper.java:47)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.ItemIDIndexMapper.map(ItemIDIndexMapper.java:31)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
13/05/16 22:48:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/05/16 22:48:54 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
13/05/16 22:48:54 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/eric.waite/temp/preparePreferenceMatrix/numUsers.bin
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSClient.java:1843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSClient.java:1834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:578)
```

My input file is very simple : (sample)
userid, storyId, rating (1-5)

```
2840281,1119,2
2840321,1170,3
2840323,1124,5
2840371,1170,5
2840347,1157,3
2840371,1172,5
2840347,1157,5
2840358,1333,5
2840371,1172,5
2840347,1157,5
```

I am trying to run a basic example using the following command :

```
hadoop jar /sourcecode/mahout/mahout-distribution-0.7/mahout-core-0.7-job.jar org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob -s SIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE --input ratings.dat --output output
```

Java information:

java version "1.7.0_13" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode) I am on a mac 10.8.2

Does anyone have any suggestions on why the integer is being read as a string and is generating the `NumberFormatException`?

Thank you.

Comment: java version "1.7.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

I am on a mac 10.8.2

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`

Comment: have put that into your question, to me it looks like a bug in the Java API (as long as we don't find any strange character between the quotes of that exception). `1119` should definitely be parsable to a long.

Comment: Can you just use the following code to check if it is a Java API bug:  System.out.println(Long.parseLong("1119"));

Comment: Of course that works in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have some non-printing character funny business in here. The string it shows, of course, parses just fine as a long. (The quotes are only part of its error message.)

To see what I mean, try

```
    System.out.println(Long.parseLong("\u00001119"));
```

It fails with the same error, one that is on its face puzzling.

Not sure how to debug this easily short of a hex editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the RecommendJob and check where the exception occurs and check the actual string value, maybe some blank or useless character in the input file.
I also have this exception, and my exception occurs here:

```
String[] tokens = TasteHadoopUtils.splitPrefTokens(value.toString());
long itemID = Long.parseLong(tokens[transpose ? 0 : 1]);
```